# apt(-get) abnormal time spent in 0% [Working]

Tags: networking, apt

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux amnesia 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

When I run any `apt` involving online activity, it stays stuck at `0% [Working]` for about 15 seconds.

My Internet connection is decent.

I read a lot of posts on this issue, so I disabled `IPv6` in both apt:

```sh
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

And `sysctl`:

```sh
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I tried `LC_ALL=C apt update` trick without any success. No luck either with `/var/lib/apt/lists` cleaning (`rm -rf`, `apt clean` and `apt update`) which I read solved the issue for some.

When `strace`'ing the process I can see it gets stuck here:

```sh
select(7, [6], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [6])
read(6, "100 Capabilities\nSend-Config: tr"..., 64000) = 64
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=242048, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease", 0x7ffdada965c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88722, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_InRelease", 0x7ffdada965c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-backports_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=74562, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-backports_InRelease", 0x7ffdada965c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_InRelease", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88724, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_InRelease", 0x7ffdada965c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
select(11, [5 6], [8 10], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 2 (out [8 10], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=499997})
write(10, "601 Configuration\nConfig-Item: A"..., 18918) = 18918
write(8, "601 Configuration\nConfig-Item: A"..., 17465) = 17465
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
0% [Working])          = 1313
select(7, [5 6], [], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=500000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [WINCH], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

Here's my `source.list`:

```sh
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

I also tried a mirror near me, same result.

I'm getting out of options...

Answer (score 0):

So I upgraded my Internet access from radio / LTE to fiber optics (Movistar) which is now available where I live and this latency vanished. 100% network related, but will remain a mystery.

No other changes. I was able to try an actual before after and there's absolutely no doubt it was related to my Internet access.